# Cordova none of the scripts are being called

Tags: javascript, cordova

So this is my `index.html`:

```html
    <body class="np">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angularjs-sanitize.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/db.js"></script>

        <div class="container-fluid" id="pageContainer"> 
        </div>
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/pages/index.js"></script>
    </body>
```

My files hierarchy is like this:

[image]

My starting html page is set in `config.xml`:

```
<content src="views/index.html" />
```

None of my scripts are being called. Why is that?

Comment: Can we see the `<meta>` tags in your HTML file? It could be that the policies outlined there are blocking your scripts

Comment: Run your app inside the browser, open the developer tools and have a look at the Console. What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

place all your script extensions inside the html head tag, and make sure the cordova.js extension comes first.